# vertical scrollbar not visible in IE and firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a tables with in the div. Scrollbar is not visible in IE and firefox due to which table data is missing within the div.

Please suggest how to make vertical scrollbar visible if data is more.

Below is my sample div code:

```
<div align="center" style="height: 100%;overflow-y:scroll; border: 2px;">

//logic to create html tables 
</div>
```

Comment: It needs more code and samples. Use jsfiddle, please. Create fiddle, test in  IE/FF and add link to question. I tried repeat your problem and I couldn't.

Comment: It is also good idea not to use inline css (unless you are creating email newsletter, or update styling dynamically via JavaScript). Also, align could be css achieved via text-align:center;

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a bug regarding this,

maybe try adding:

```
html { height: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; }
.divname { min-height: 100%; margin:auto;overflow-y:scroll;border: 2px;
```

}

```
<div id="divname"> 
//logic to create html tables 
</div>
```